# WPF TextBox with Label

Tags: .net, wpf, textbox

I need a TextBox with a label in it.  The label should disappear when the user clicks inside the TextBox and begins typing.  Before I go off and write my own, is there some out-of-the-box control out there that will fill this requirement?  I'm just not seeing it in my searching.  I'm using C#, .Net 4.0, XAML, etc...